# Heroku not compiling javascripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, asset-pipeline

I'm having real trouble with Heroku. It seems it's compiling CSS now, but still JS is not being compiled. I'm using Foundation 5 and Rails 4. Any idea?

production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/modernizr.js )
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true`
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require foundation
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.lockfixed
//= require sticky_footer
//= require list
//= require foundation.slider
//= require landing
//= require handlebars
//= require landing
//= require foundation.abide

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably committed your assets to your git repo.
You can

```
# add assets to git ignore
echo "public/assets" >> .gitignore
# remove them from your git repo and from public
git rm -rf public/assets
# update your repo
git add public
git commit -m "Removed assets from repo"
# push to heroku again
git push heroku master
```